# R glmnet force coefficients to sum up to 1

Tags: r, optimization, regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

I was wondering if it is possible that in R package glmnet that we force the coefficients to sum up to 1? As if those coefficients are weights between [0,1] of individual predictors?

I figured out how to force coef to be between [0,1] using :

```
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(X,y, lower.limits=rep(0,ncol(X)), 
               upper.limits=rep(1,ncol(X)))
```

And I figured out how to force intercept to be zero using:

```
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(X,y, lower.limits=rep(0,ncol(X)), 
               upper.limits=rep(1,ncol(X)), intercept=FALSE)
```

But I don't know how to make coefficients to sum up to 1.

Thanks!

All the best,

Kathy